# Not able to save a transparent PNG to the Camera Roll using AIR on Android?

Tags: flash, air

I've created an AIR app that can already save an image to the CameraRoll. However, I'm not able to save an image with transparency to the CameraRoll. I thought this was working at one point. Instead, it's saving a highly compressed JPG.

**More info**:
I'm using CameraRoll.addBitmapData() and AIR 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a [bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3205096) in AIR in version 3.3 and on. I think it was working before that but I would have to test.

Please vote for this [bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3205096).